# Confusion understanding filter visualization tool output in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design

My MATLAB code is

```
d = fdesign.bandpass(.3, .4, .6, .7, 80, .5, 60);
    Hd = design(d, 'ellip');
    fvtool(Hd)
```

when i run my script , i see two graphs on output as shown in attached snapshot, one graph is solid line and other is dotted line, what is difference between those two graphs?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solid blue is the designed filter response while the dashed red lines are the design constraints from your command:

1. First stopband frequency is set to 0.3.
2. First passband frequency is set to 0.4.
3. Second passband frequency is set to 0.6.
4. Second stopband frequency is set to 0.7.
5. First stopband attenuation is set to at least 80 dB.
6. Passband ripple is set to at most 0.5 dB.
7. Second stopband attenuation is set to at least 60 dB.

Comment: you mean,dotted line is desired and solid line is practical/actual response??

Comment: No. For example, second stopband attenuation is set to **at least** 60 dB. See the updated text